# .SVG image displays on Safari, IE, iOS and Android but not Firefox or Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I did a search for similar issues and couldn't find the solution.

I want to use an SVG image for the centre logo on this website www.robearnshaw.com.

I had this working previously but now after installing the regular SVG support plugin on Wordpress, the image is just not rendered on Firefox or Chrome but displays fine on all other browsers I've tried. I've tried several SVG formats and the results don't change. Looking at the assets on Chrome shows that the link to the file is there. It just doesn't display on the web page itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include your source code in the question (a MCVE). Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose much of its value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your SVG logo elements with the browser tools. You will see immediately what the problem is.  The computed width and height of the `<img>` are 0px.

The cause of the problem is that bitmap images like JPEGs and PNGs have an intrinsic width and height.  That is not always true of SVG files.  Your logo SVG is an example of one that doesn't, because it does not specify a width or height in it's root `<svg>` tag.  So `width: auto` will not work in this case.

The solution is to either:

1. Add `width` and `height` attributes to your SVG file.
2. Specify a width in your CSS instead of using `auto`.  For example:

   ```
   .fusion-logo img {
       width: 100px;
   }
   ```